# Removing unremovable system fonts

Tags: high-sierra, font

Does anyone know how I can remove some fonts (that I know I'll never use) from my Mac?

Some fonts don't allow you to remove them, and these are often the ones that I want to remove.

[image]

I want to remove the fonts to free up some space, and also to reduce the long list of fonts in sub-menus.

Comment: Fonts don't take up much room, relatively speaking. You're better off using something like Onyx to clear out cache files, old iTunes iDevice (iPhone, iPad) backups, old .ipsw files (iOS installers,) etc. You're bound to recover far more disk space that way.

Comment: For some info on macos font management, see http://www.jklstudios.com/misc/osxfonts.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard macOS fonts can't be removed since they are components of macOS. Built-in fonts are protected by SIP, and even if you manually remove the font files, they will be restored on macOS update.